# Most efficient way for creation of mapping based on 2 Mongo collections

Tags: python, mongodb, algorithm

I am working with MongoDB using MongoEngine in Python, and I need to create a mapping from each OrchestrationUser's user_id to a list of UserGroup's id values. Specifically, the OrchestrationUser's group_ids should be used to find matching groups in the UserGroup.orchestrations_groups list.

Here are my MongoEngine models (which cannot be changed):

```
class OrchestrationUser(Document):
    user_id = StringField(required=True, primary_key=True)
    group_ids = ListField(StringField())

class OrchestrationGroup(EmbeddedDocument):
    group_id = StringField()
    group_name = StringField()

class OrchestrationGroups(EmbeddedDocument):
    orchestration_id = StringField()
    groups = ListField(EmbeddedDocumentField(OrchestrationGroup))

class UserGroup(Document):
    id = StringField(required=True, primary_key=True, default=lambda: str(uuid.uuid4()))
    orchestrations_groups = ListField(EmbeddedDocumentField(OrchestrationGroups))
```

Constraints:

Maximum number of OrchestrationUser instances: 160,000
Maximum number of UserGroup instances: 250
Each group_ids list and orchestrations_groups.groups list can contain 1-1000 IDs.
My goal is to create a mapping like this: {orch_user_id: [user_group_ids]}.

**Here's a code snippet representing example of my current solution:**

```
def map_users_to_usergroups():
    import datetime
    from itertools import chain
    from collections import defaultdict
    from ... import OrchestrationUser, UserGroup

    start_time = datetime.datetime.utcnow()
    group_to_usergroup_mapping = {}
    pipeline = [
        {'$unwind': '$orchestrations_groups'},
        {'$unwind': '$orchestrations_groups.groups'},
        {
            '$group': {
                '_id': '$orchestrations_groups.groups.group_id',
                'user_group_ids': {'$addToSet': '$_id'}
            }
        },
        {
            '$project': {
                '_id': 0,
                'group_id': '$_id',
                'user_group_ids': 1
            }
        }
    ]

    print("Starting aggregation of user groups...")
    for entry in UserGroup.objects.aggregate(*pipeline):
        group_to_usergroup_mapping[entry['group_id']] = entry['user_group_ids']
    print(f"Aggregation complete. Total {len(group_to_usergroup_mapping)}")

    user_to_usergroups_mapping = defaultdict(set)
    last_user_id = None

    print("Mapping users to user groups...")
    while True:
        query = OrchestrationUser.objects.order_by('user_id')
        if last_user_id is not None:
            query = query.filter(user_id__gt=last_user_id)
        chunk = query[:5000]

        if not chunk:
            break

        for orchestration_user in chunk:
            user_to_usergroups_mapping[orchestration_user.user_id].update(
                chain.from_iterable(
                    group_to_usergroup_mapping.get(group_id, [])
                    for group_id in orchestration_user.group_ids
                    if group_id in group_to_usergroup_mapping
                )
            )
            last_user_id = orchestration_user.user_id

        print(f"Processed chunk up to user_id: {last_user_id}")

    total_time = (datetime.datetime.utcnow() - start_time).total_seconds()
    print(f"Took {total_time} seconds.")
    
    return user_to_usergroups_mapping

user_to_usergroups_mapping = map_users_to_usergroups()
```

**Example Data:**

```
// OrchestrationUsers
[
  {"user_id": "orch_user_1", "group_ids": ["group_1", "group_2"]},
  {"user_id": "orch_user_2", "group_ids": ["group_2", "group_3"]}
]

// UserGroups
[
  {
    "id": "user_group_1",
    "orchestrations_groups": [
      {
        "orchestration_id": "orch_1",
        "groups": [
          {"group_id": "group_1", "group_name": "Group One"},
          {"group_id": "group_2", "group_name": "Group Two"}
        ]
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "id": "user_group_2",
    "orchestrations_groups": [
      {
        "orchestration_id": "orch_2",
        "groups": [
          {"group_id": "group_3", "group_name": "Group Three"}
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

**Expected Result:**

```
{
    "orch_user_1": ["user_group_1"],
    "orch_user_2": ["user_group_1", "user_group_2"]
}
```

**Currently, the solution is quite time-consuming, so I am on the lookout for a more intelligent and efficient algorithm for matching, searching, and mapping. Any assistance would be greatly appreciated, thank you! Please note, I would prefer to avoid using temporary databases in MongoDB for aggregation solutions.**